# Replace fonts by converting PDF to PDF/A

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdfbox

I faced a problem while developing converter from pdf to pdf/a. I use PDFBox library.  I need not only convert existing pdf to pdf/a, but also replace font. In input pdf are used standart Helvetica and Courier. I want to replace Helvetica with another font. Is it possible to do it without re-rendering?

Comment: If you use a font with the same metrics (in particular same character widths), no re-rendering should be required.

Comment: Thanks for reply, do you have experience, how to do it? Font to replace seems to be very  similiar.

Comment: *"do you have experience how to do it?"* - No, I didn't have to do that yet. *"Font to replace seems to be very similiar."* - Do yourself a favor and check whether the metrics (in particular the character widths) coincide with those of the fonts to replace. Furthermore, check whether your replacement fonts are complete enough, they should at least contain the glyphs from Annex D of ISO 32000.

Comment: Are you aware that there can be hundreds of things to fix when converting a PDF to PDF/A-1b? If you have files that are all similar and only have the fonts and the output intents to fix, then go for it. If you want to convert all possible files, then you should by a product from companies like Callas or PDF-Tools.

Comment: One might try to replace the font in the font resources with a TT font without subsetting, by creating the font with `PDType0Font.load(doc, is, false)`.